# 100% width header with javascript issue?

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox

I have been trying to put a full 100% width header which I found here: http://codecanyon.net/item/full-width-slider-2/3430907

on my website. but because I already have modal popup on my website, as soon as I use that header, the modal pop-up (I am using Fancy Box) stops functionening correctly and it opens a new page window to show its contents!! this is very strange and I don't understand why these two conflict.

any chance anyone could point me in a right direction to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Do they both use jQuery? Or is one of them using MooTools/Prototype.js?

Comment: what code do you want to see? I have not changed any code from the link mentioned above and the modal popup (fancy box). I basically copy and pasted everything as they were in a page!

Comment: @LexEichner, I am not entirely sure but I think they both use jQuery.

Comment: @LexEichner, yes they are both jQuery. why? does that make any difference?

Comment: @user2056633 We do want to help, but don't expect people to go look for, and download the scripts. Therefor we ask you to post them in your question.

Comment: @user2056633 Yes it can do. Prototype, jQuery and Mootools can conflict with each other. But if they both use jQuery then that isn't the answer. That being the case, we will need the code to help.